# Status of a file in java

Tags: java, io

How to know the status of a file, that is, if application is blocked and it is blocking. In java, if there is an API for this or you can use Java IO.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about file locks, the following example from [Example Depot](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/SetFileLock.html) shows how to use it :

```
try {
    // Get a file channel for the file
    File file = new File("filename");
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

    // Use the file channel to create a lock on the file.
    // This method blocks until it can retrieve the lock.
    FileLock lock = channel.lock();

    // Try acquiring the lock without blocking. This method returns
    // null or throws an exception if the file is already locked.
    try {
        lock = channel.tryLock();
    } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
        // File is already locked in this thread or virtual machine
    }

    // Release the lock
    lock.release();

    // Close the file
    channel.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: ok but how I can know which application is blocking it? catching the exception I can tell?

Comment: Sorry, the API does not state anything about that :(

Comment: Application may not know but I block it solves the main problem.

Thank you very much.